# C# syntax, assign delegate to a class, and call later

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a bit of confusion with this C# syntax.
I'm trying to assign an arbitrary delegate to a class.

**I have a delegates defined as**

```
delegate string stringCB(string s);
delegate int intCB(int i);
```

**I have a class**

```
class run_by_name {
    public string name {get;set;}
    public Delegate method {get;set;}
};
```

**And I'm trying to instantiate it**

```
 run_by_name myfuc = new run_by_name(){
     name = "my name",
     method = new stringCB(string s) {
         return " testing " + s;
     };
 };
```

I'm really not clear how to assign to a delegate when there's a return type. Also I'm not sure **how to call that method later** on syntactically.

*Why I'm doing this?* Well I'm just writing some code that follows a pattern I use in JS a lot for event handling, I'm just making an "object" I can assign arbitrary functions to for a generic event handler that's **created rather than defined.** (important)

Also, alternatives to using delegates are welcome. :)

*EDIT: How I might use it later*
I don't have that written yet but Im pretty sure I'll be doing this.

```
List<run_by_name> callbacks = new List<run_by_name>();
/* lets say this is initialized and filled at this point */

public object FindAndRunCallback(string Name, object input) {
    foreach(var cb in callbacks) {
        if( cb.name == Name )
            return cb.method(input);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: why don't you use actual events? Checkout `Action<T>` and `Func<T>` and their siblings.

Comment: You should look at [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Instead of `method = new stringCB(string s) { return " testing " + s; };` you need to write `method = (string s) => (" testing " + s);`.

Comment: How would one use Action<T>, that was my original approach but I ran into the same kind of syntax issue.

Comment: Side note: you may be better off if you start from other end - decide how you want your methods to be called (using compilable syntax) and than design your classes... At least consider showing how you would like to call them by name and arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the syntax you need to get your current code working:

```
 method = new stringCB((string s) =>  {
     return " testing " + s;
 })
```

Or, using lambda expressions:

```
 method = new stringCB(s =>" testing " + s)
```

You could later invoke the method like so:

```
string result = (string) myfuc.method.DynamicInvoke("hello");
```

Without knowing more about your use case, it's hard to recommend other approaches, but I'd recommend at least looking into the following:

- Events: Your description sounds very close to the common pattern for events and event handlers in C#. Your event defines the delegate type that is used to handle it, and code elsewhere can subscribe to that event with methods that match that delegate type. By convention, people usually pass a sender `object` as the first parameter, and some strongly-typed `EventArgs` so that subscribers don't have to guess at what data is going to be available when the event fires.
- `Func<>` and `Action<>` variants: As C# has evolved into a more functional language, programmers have trended away from using custom delegate types, and toward using the provided variants of `Func<>` and `Action<>`. Since the arguments are strongly-typed still, you get most of the advantages of a compiled language, but use a little "duck typing" for the actual function you pass around.

  For example, you could give your class a generic type based on what types you expect your delegate to deal with:

  ```
  class run_by_name<T> {
      public string name {get;set;}
      public Func<T, T> method {get;set;}
  };
  ```

  Then use it:

  ```
  var myfuc = new run_by_name<string>{
      name = "my name",
      method = s =>" testing " + s
  };

  string result = myfuc.method("hello");
  ```
- `dynamic`: This keyword allows you to late-bind actions on any object. You lose the advantages of a compiled language, but it improves interoperability with more dynamic languages immensely. For example, an object can be created via JSON, and you can access the properties on it without declaring a special type for that object, just like you can in Javascript.

  For example, if you changed your `method` declaration to this:

  ```
  public dynamic method {get;set;}
  ```

  Then you could simply say:

  ```
  string result = myfuc.method("hello");
  ```

Comment: You should also address the `how to call that method later` question.

Comment: This is great, definitely solved my confusion, also good to know how to use the lambda operator like that.

Answer (score 2):

You have seceral choices. the `strinCB` constructor expects a method, that takes a string parameter and returns a string. If you have an existing method, you can pass it's name to the constructor, or you can create an anonymous method wither by delegate syntax like this:

```
method = new stringCB(delegate(string s)
            {
                return " testing " + s;
            })
```

Or using a lambda expression:

```
method = new stringCB(s =>
            {
                return " testing " + s;
            })
```

Then you can call it like this: `myfuc.method.DynamicInvoke(YourParameter);`

Normally, calling a delegate's method is pretty easy like this:

```
Func<int, int, int> sum = (x, y) => x + y;

Console.WriteLine(sum(2,3)); // with the name of delegate

Console.WriteLine(sum.Invoke(2,3)); // or using Invoke method
```

But in this case, you need to use `DynamicInvoke` because the type of your property is `Delegate`.

Apart from that `.NET Framework` has some useful built-in delegate types, such as [`Func`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),[`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Predicate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) etc. You can use them instead of creating your own delegate as long as they satisfy your needs. For example in this case you can use a `Func<string,string>` instead of `stringCB`.